# Need to paas JSON array with POST body using collection runner as array has 5000 + indexes

Tags: json, api, postman

I have a POST API and need to pass the request body as variable as the request body JSON array has 5000 + indexes.
Sample Request Body

```
[ 
   { 
      "code":"1",
      "Center":"1",
      "name":"CC_name_00111",
      "description":"",
      "erpId":"",

   },
   { 
      "code":"2",
      "Center":"2",
      "name":"CC_name_0011",
      "description":"",
      "erpId":"",

   }
]
```

The API should run only once with all the complete request body. Need help on how to achieve this.

Comment: No  one will suggest  you to post such large data set in a request API. Rather use pagination for such large requests as server performance will hinder.

Comment: I need to test this API as the API  already accepts the response through pagination.How can this be tested

Comment: Can you post the code of your API ?